# Parsing NSDictionary result of grouped by fetch request in Core Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I need to get some statistics from table using CoreData. I have used [this](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2017/04/group-by-count-and-sum-in-coredata/) manual to extract data using "group by" expressions.

Here is my source code:

```
var popularGuestNames: [String] = []
        let keypathExp = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "guestName")
        let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [keypathExp])

        let countDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
        countDesc.expression = expression
        countDesc.name = "count"
        countDesc.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "GuestsTable")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        request.propertiesToGroupBy = ["guestName"]
        request.propertiesToFetch = ["guestName", countDesc]
        request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

        let matchedGuests = try? context.fetch(request)
        guard matchedGuests != nil else {return popularGuestNames}
```

But as a results I am getting matchedGuests with type [Any]. And I stuck here. I can see using print that there is JSON object:

```
Optional(
[{
    count = 1;
    guestName = "\U0412\U0430\U043d\U044f";
}, {
    count = 13;
    guestName = "\U0413\U043e\U0441\U0442\U044c 1";
}, {
    count = 9;
    guestName = "\U0413\U043e\U0441\U0442\U044c 2";
}, {
    count = 3;
    guestName = "\U0413\U043e\U0441\U0442\U044c 3";
}, {
    count = 1;
    guestName = "\U0413\U043e\U0441\U0442\U044c 4";
}, {
    count = 1;
    guestName = "\U0413\U043e\U0441\U0442\U044c 5";
}, {
    count = 1;
    guestName = "\U041d\U043d\U043d";
}, {
    count = 1;
    guestName = "\U0422\U0435\U0441\U0442";
}, {
    count = 1;
    guestName = "\U0422\U0435\U0441\U0442 \U0442\U0435\U0441\U0442\U043e\U0432\U0438\U0447";
}, {
    count = 1;
    guestName = "\U0423\U0410\U0443\U043f\U0430\U0438\U0443\U0430\U0433\U0443";
}])
```

But I cannot find the way how to parse it. I know that I should use JSONSerialization.jsonObject, but this method expects input variable in Data type. And I cannot understand how to convert Any to Data.

Comment: `matchedGuests` is an array of dictionaries: `[[String:Any]]`. `Any` being a String for key `guestName`, and what I guess an `Int` for key `count`

Comment: As I can see from editor: let matchedGuests: [Any]? . How to work with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the result of a Core Data fetch is definitely **not** a JSON object

Second of all **be more specific!**

Since the return type of the fetch request is clearly  dictionary use the generic type to pass `NSDictionary`

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "GuestsTable")
```

Then cast the type accordingly to the actual type `[[String:Any]]`.

```
var matchedGuests = [[String:Any]]()
...
if let result = try? context.fetch(request) as! [[String:Any]] {
   matchedGuests = result
}
```

Even if an `try?` error occurs the forced unwrapped return type will never cause a crash assuming the fetch request is valid.

---

If you want only the guest names `map` the array

```
let popularGuestNames = matchedGuests.flatMap { $0["guestName"] as? String }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Just one not related question is left. Can you advise how to use SortDescriptor for added column "count"? If I use sort descriptor it fails         request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "count", ascending: true)]

Comment: I don't know how `NSExpression` affects the fetch request but you can sort the array after the fetch: `matchedGuests.sorted(by: {$0["count"] as! Int < $1["count"] as! Int})`

Answer (score 1):

`matchedGuests` is an Array of Dictionaries, or `[[String:Any]]`. To use this, you could iterate through it using a `for in` loop.

```
for dic in matchedGuests {
    //Dic will be a dictionary in the array with key value pairs.
    print(dic["count"])
    print(dic["guestName"])
    .... do more work with results.
}
```

To use the value for Any cast it to a String if you know it's type.

```
let string = dic["guestName"] as? String
```